# Please Help With Old OSS Sound Application

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, oss

I'm having super hard time trying to make an ancient programm (TeamSpeak2) to work under ubuntu 20.04 (tried with several versions of ubuntu same result). After weeks of googleing, I maybe found the problem. The program starts but I can't hear no sound whatsoever. I've tried to commence ossinfo and this is the result

```
Version info:   (0x00000000)
Platform: Linux/x86_64 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 (dex)

Number of audio devices:        0
Number of audio engines:        0
Number of MIDI devices:         0
Number of mixer devices:        0


Device objects

MIDI devices (/dev/midi*)

Mixer devices

Audio devices

Nodes
```

it looks like the oss driver can't find any sound card while I have got two. I can't disable pulseaudio even if btw I've tried with no effect at all.
I know ubuntu has deprecated support to all OSS world (can't get why btw...), but I know several pepole under ubuntu can run old OSS sound application with no issue. So maybe there's a way to fixit.
I've got all the alsa and osspd packages on.

Do you know how can I make the OSS driver to see my cards please?

thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: Did you start osspd?

Comment: Hi,you mean with padsp ./TeamSpeak?. I did but there's a 64\32 bits library incompatibility issue I can't resolve